# C++ check if a string contains numbers and . only

Tags: c++, string, lambda, split, number-formatting

I want to know if there is a lambda or a clean short format in order to find if a single string contains only numeric values e.g 0 - 9 and the full stop character e.g . only.
For example string "123.45" should pass and strings "12jd", "12.4f" etc should fail.

Comment: `std::stod`, and use the second parameter.

Comment: @sweenish thanks for the reply, sorry what do you mean by second parameter?

Comment: Does it need to be a legal number? For instance, would `001` or `1.1...1` pass the test?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I should've clarified this, but yes 001 can pass but no more then 1 . should be present so 1.1....1 should not work

Comment: Based on your description the string "1.1.1.2.3.456" would also pass the given criteria. Is this what you want?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No sorry it should only have one .

Answer (score 1):

This would be the code for your check, the constexpr stuff makes the function evaluatable at compile time. And the static_assert checks the output at compile time. Basically doing a unit test at compile time.

string_view is a nice wrapper for string literals and makes the string literal more easy to pass into the function and allows the use of a range based for loop to loop over all the characters.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string_view>

constexpr bool is_positive_number(const std::string_view number_string)
{
    std::size_t number_of_points{ 0ul };

    // loop over all characters in string
    for (const auto character : number_string)
    {
        // a '.' is valid but there should only be one
        if (character == '.')
        {
            number_of_points++;
            if (number_of_points > 1) return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // if character is not a '.' then it must be betweern '0'-'9'
            if ((character < '0') || (character > '9')) return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_positive_number("1"));
    static_assert(is_positive_number("12"));
    static_assert(is_positive_number("123"));
    static_assert(is_positive_number("1."));
    static_assert(is_positive_number("1.2"));
    static_assert(is_positive_number("12.34"));
    static_assert(is_positive_number("007"));

    static_assert(!is_positive_number("12.3.4"));
    static_assert(!is_positive_number("-123"));
    static_assert(!is_positive_number("abc"));

    //auto lambda = [](const char* number_string)
    auto lambda = [](const std::string& number_string)
    {
        return is_positive_number(number_string);
    };

    auto is_ok = lambda("123");
    assert(is_ok);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: THank you this seems good! is it possible to make this in to a lambda?

Comment: Why is number is points of type size_t? Wouldn't short or even Boolean suffice?

Comment: Sure but what should the signature of your lambda be? e.g. what parameters does it need to accept or does it need to capture a string?

Comment: @infinitezero Because you can have either 0 or 1 points and both are fine. It is at 2 the string no longer is ok. But yeah it could work with a bool if you encounter a '.' and a bool called 'has_dot' is already true. The code would just look a little different

Comment: @PepijnKramer just 1 parameter the input string, just return a bool

Comment: You really shouldnt be passing `std::string_view` by reference, otherwise you might as well just use a `std::string` reference. Same with looping through characters of a string. Making a trivial copy of  is often better and more performant as well.

Comment: Example updated with lambda's and @AyxanHaqverdili thanks keep forgetting that.

Comment: @JaneDoe If your source is a char pointer and you accept a std::string it will create the object which incurs a string copy always while with std::string_view it will not.

Comment: @JaneDoe string_view& and const auto& for chars noted, udpated :)

Comment: @Jellyboi True but that doesnt change the fact that passing `std::string_view` by reference is just a bad idea.

https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/11/09/pass-string-view-by-value/

Comment: What difference it makes? Why is it a "bad idea"?

Comment: Oh well to be honest I didn't put this through compiler explorer to optimize every last bit out of it ;) And then there are all the possibilities of r-value string types didn't want to go through these either.

Comment: @Jellyboy I think the page Jane linked to explains it pretty good :)

Comment: The page is specific to x86_64 assembly and even then it makes zero difference on all the cases stated.

Comment: The name `is_positive_number` isn't correct; the code tests for a non-negative value.

Comment: "007" should not be accepted as a valid floating point number but I guess it's within OP's statement

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use the open-source [compile-time regex library](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions):

```
#include <ctre.hpp>

constexpr bool is_positive_number(std::string_view const s) noexcept {
    return static_cast<bool>(ctre::match<R"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)">(s));
}

int main() {
    static_assert(is_positive_number("1.2"));
    static_assert(!is_positive_number("1..2"));
    static_assert(!is_positive_number("1e2"));
}
```

[See Online](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ah6Gq5PnW)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a straightforward scan of the text:

```
bool is_valid(const std::string& str) {
    int dots = 0;
    for (char c: str) {
        if (c == '.')
            ++dots;
        if (1 < dots || !std::isdigit(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should cast the argument of `isdigit` to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili -- I'm not that paranoid.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili -- withe quoted text there is no need for that cast; the code is correct as written. Feel free to comment on the limits, but don't insist that there is one true way.

Answer (score 0):

Using std::regex produces a two-liner if you dont count the static pattern

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <cassert>

bool is_positive_number( const std::string& str ) {
    static std::regex rx("^(\\+?)(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\\.[0-9]*)?$");             // Getting the regex object 
    std::smatch match;
    return std::regex_match(str,match,rx);
}

int main()
{
    assert(is_positive_number("1"));
    assert(is_positive_number("12"));
    assert(is_positive_number("123"));
    assert(is_positive_number("1."));
    assert(is_positive_number("1.2"));
    assert(is_positive_number("12.34"));
    assert(is_positive_number("+12.34"));
    assert(!is_positive_number("007"));

    assert(!is_positive_number("123.23.23"));
    assert(!is_positive_number("-123"));
    assert(!is_positive_number("abc"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It also generates [21K lines of assembly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9Y73c1sb6).

Comment: Was that a requirement in OP's statement?

Comment: I am pointing out that `std::regex` implementations are highly inefficient.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Notoriously inefficient, you are 100% correct.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a built-in function that does exactly what you were looking for. There is `std::stod` that converts a `string` into a `double` and tells you how many characters were converted successfully. However, there are many non-conforming numbers that will work, such as `-1`, `NAN`, `10E+3`.

---

One way you could do is first remove all numbers(0~9), then check against `""` and `"."`:

```cpp
constexpr bool is_num(std::string str)
{
    std::erase_if(str, [](unsigned char c){ return std::isdigit(c);};
    return str == "" || str == ".";
}
```

Note `erase_if` is from C++20, for pre-C++20, you would do:

```cpp
constexpr bool is_num(std::string str)
{
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), 
              [](unsigned char c){ return std::isdigit(c); }), str.end());
    return str == "" || str == ".";
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vWbocx3rs)